# IIS7 to IIS6 migration web.config problems

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config, iis-6

I have a web application that I wrote in Visual Studio 2008 that targets .Net Framework 3.5.  To test it I used a machine running Windows 7, which means IIS7.  My application works just fine on this but when it was deployed to a development server (running server 2003, so IIS6) it doesn't work.

The first few lines of my web.config file are as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
```

The error I get has to do with the type= part of the sectionGroup tag.  I don't remember the exact message, but it is something along the lines of 'invalid tag' or 'invalid attribute.'

I have two questions:

- First, is anyone savvy enough with IIS to know why this works in 7 and not 6?
- Second, why do I need the sectionGroup tag?  What  does it do?

I checked the dev server to make sure the right version of .net was installed.  It has 2, 3, 3.5, and 4, so I should be covered on that front.

I'm rather new to .net (probably obvious by now), so please forgive me if this has been asked a thousand times and it looks like I'm beating dead horses.  My googling and searching of stackoverflow didn't provide a solution.

SOLUTION: 
The whole problem was IIS not being configured correctly.  The asp.net tab of the website's properties was set to 2.0.something.  We changed it to 4.0.something (3.5 wasn't an option) and everything works just fine.

Comment: Are you sure that the virtual directory is targeting the correct version of the .Net framework?

Comment: Did you set the asp.net tab to 2.0.*** on the IIS6 application properties? Also should keep it in a 2.0 only app pool...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your framework targets .NET 3.5. It probably doesn't matter whether you use the scripting section or not, but the scripting section is configured with 3.5. This is used for the client scripts of the ASP.NET Ajax Scripts.

If you run your application in IIS 6, it depends on which framework version you have configured for the application pool. If you mix your applications, it might start in the wrong version. Check that you configure your pool correctly. Unfortunately I don't have an IIS 6 here I can't remember exactly how you do that. Important is that you have no other application in another .NET version running in the same pool.

Comment: I'm not actually using Ajax (tried something during development that didnt' work), so I can probably get rid of those lines and be fine then.  I checked my app pool, and it's using 2.0.something on the local IIS 7 server.  I'll have to wait until after lunch to get access to the IIS 6 server again.  I'll post updates when I get them.

Comment: I doesn't matter whehter you use Ajax or not, you probably still want to use the .NET 3.5 features. You always configure .NET 2.0 in IIS because that ist the CLR version. But if you mix to applications of different .NET versions, you get into this trouble.

Comment: The app pool was configured correctly, but the site was set on the wrong version of .NET framework.  Funny how simple things can be so easily overlooked.